# Output all the words that do not appear in the second sentence

Tags: java

could you take a look at my code and tell me why it doesn't work as supposed --

```
   String word1 = "Simple sentence that is first";
    String word2 = "Another sentence that is second.";
    appear(word1, word2);
}
static void appear(String word1, String word2){
    String[] split = word1.split(" ");
    String[] split2 = word2.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i <= split.length - 1; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j <= split2.length - 1; j++){
            if (!split[i].equals(split2[j])){
                System.out.println(split[i]);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

the output should be: Simple and first since they are the only two words that do not appear in the 2nd sentence. And my output is all the words from the first sentence repeated several times. Should't (!.equals) work?

Comment: Condition `<=` on the index in zero based string length comparisons seems wrong. Don't you need to populate the cache (i-loop) first and when that is done do the matching (j-loop)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this way you are checking if each word of the first sentence is equal to each word of the second. This means that for the word sentence, for example, it will check if it's equal to another and if not it will porint, then it will check if it's equal to sentence and so on. If you want to print you should keep track if a word of the first sentence appears in the second

```
String word1 = "Simple sentence that is first";
String word2 = "Another sentence that is second.";
appear(word1, word2);
}
static void appear(String word1, String word2){
    String[] split = word1.split(" ");
    String[] split2 = word2.split(" ");
    boolean appeared;
    for (int i = 0; i <= split.length - 1; i++){
        appeared = false;
        for (int j = 0; j <= split2.length - 1; j++){
            if (split[i].equals(split2[j])){
                appeared = true;
            }
        }
    if(appeared == false)
        System.out.println(split[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

String has contains() method which you can rely on to search if each word in 1st sentence is present in second sentence.

```
    String[] split = word1.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i <= split.length - 1; i++){
    if(!Arrays.asList(word2.split(" ")).contains(split[i])){
      System.out.println(split[i]);
    }
    }
```

Using Java8 Streams, the above can be modified into single line as below.

```
Arrays.asList(word1.split(" ")).stream().filter(x->!Arrays.asList(word2.split(" ")).contains(x)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: This only works for the provided and not the general case. For example, if word1 contains the word "stop" and word2 contains the word "stopsign".

Comment: @Alchemy you're right. This would fail in cases you mentioned. Upvoted your answer. Will correct mine.

Answer (score 1):

The key to your problem is a data structure known as a Set. [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/set-in-java/) has a fairly good introduction.

With sets we can model the problem as the difference between two sets of strings.
I tried to name the variables consistently with that Geeks for Geeks article so you can follow along.

```
Set<String> a = new HashSet<>(); 
Set<String> b = new HashSet<>();
a.addAll(word1.split(" "));
// a is now {"Simple" "sentence" "that" "is", "first"}
b.addAll(word2.split(" "));
// b is now {"Another", "sentence", "that", "is", "second";

// We can now calculate the difference
a.removeAll(b);
// a is now {"Simple", "first"}

// Because sets are iterable we can finish via a for-each loop
for(String s : a) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```